# I want to subtract two currency numbers

Tags: php

I want to subtract two numbers but both of them have currency. (25$-10$)

```
<?php
    $tamount= $agreementdata['amount'];
    $eamount= $agreementdata['earnestamount'];
    $ramount= $agreementdata['amount'-'earnestamount'];  
    echo $ramount;
?>
```

Comment: This seems like a fairly simple problem with more than enough resource on the internet. What research did you do?

Comment: $agreementdata['amount'-'earnestamount']; // This is cool! :)

Comment: there are some nice javascript libraries that exist for currency related equations, where accuracy is very important, when I get back to PC i will try and find the one i used to use.  if i remember correctly, it came highly recommended by experienced developers etc.

Comment: update:  just did a search through an old repo and found [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js) is what i used in the past, perhaps worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $currencyFrom = '25$';
  $currency = '20$';
  $results = (int)substr($currencyFrom, 0, -1) - (int)substr($currency, 0, -1);
  echo $results;
```

I hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

From

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

**Converting to integer : From strings**

> If the string is numeric or leading numeric then it will resolve to the corresponding integer value, otherwise it is converted to zero (0).

So `(int)'25$'` will return `25`, and add the dollar sign back on so that it can be understood by the array.

```
echo (int)'25$'-(int)'20$'.'$';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more flexibility, I would work with regex.

```
$str = '25$ 10Rupiah 25 $ 10 Rupiah';
$pattern = '/[A-Z|\$]*/i'; 
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);

// output 25 10 25  10
```

That will look for your case:

```
<?php
    function getAmount($str) {
       $pattern = '/[A-Z|\$]*/i'; 
       return (int) preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
    }

    $tamount= getAmount( $agreementdata['amount'] );
    $eamount= getAmount( $agreementdata['earnestamount'] );
    $ramount= $agreementdata['amount'-'earnestamount'];  
    echo $ramount;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
     $tamount= $agreementdata['amount'];
     $eamount= $agreementdata['earnestamount'];
     $ramount=  $tamount - $eamount;

     echo $ramount;
?>
```